# Deploy x86 and x64 artifacts to AppVeyor on Github Releases

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, msbuild, continuous-integration, appveyor

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution that consists of a single C++ project.

I wanted AppVeyor to **build** for `x86` and `x64` and **deploy** the 2 executables on `GitHub Releases`.

While deploying only for one arch seems to work fine I found out that my `appveyor.yml` file replaces the executable once a job finishes and another starts.

For the record, this is my first deployment ever so I would need some guidance.

Here is some info on `Github Releases` https://www.appveyor.com/docs/deployment/github/

Here is my `appveyor.yml` file

```
version: '{build}'
image: Visual Studio 2017
configuration: Release
platform:
- x86
- x64
build:
  verbosity: minimal
artifacts:
- path: Release\pathfinding.exe
  name: pathfinding-x86.exe
- path: x64\Release\pathfinding.exe
  name: pathfinding-x64.exe
deploy:
- provider: GitHub
  auth_token:
    secure: the-token-is-hidden-on-purpose
  force_update: true
  on:
    APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Here is my repository by the way: https://github.com/xorz57/pathfinding

The problem was my visual studio build tree.
If you use the default visual studio project properties the executable files have the exact same filename even though they are on a different directory when you build for `x86` and `x64` and that's why appveyor never uploaded a second executable to `GitHub Releases`. So I went to visual studio and opened up my project settings to change the build tree.

[image]

Make sure to change Configuration to `All Configurations` and Platform to `All Platforms`. Then proceed to change the following three options `Output Directory`, `Intermediate Directory`, `Target Name`. In the picture above I show you how I configured my own project. Of course this is not the only way nor I am suggesting this is the best prossible way to organize your project.

**The point is to have different filename for the executable files**.

Now I push a new tag and everything works as intended.

[image]

And here is my updated `appveyor.yml` file

```
version: '{build}'
image: Visual Studio 2017
configuration: Release
platform:
- x86
- x64
build:
  parallel: true
  verbosity: minimal
artifacts:
- path: Build\Release\pathfinding-x86.exe
  name: pathfinding-x86.exe
- path: Build\Release\pathfinding-x64.exe
  name: pathfinding-x64.exe
deploy:
- provider: GitHub
  auth_token:
    secure: the-token-is-hidden-on-purpose
  force_update: true
  on:
    APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG: true
```

Comment: You can also simplify `artifacts` with a single line `- path: Build\Release\pathfinding-$(platform).exe`

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I am glad to hear that.